# Working with two dimensional dataset in Bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm writing a script to automate some backup routines. They involve drawing data from multiple hosts. It seems to me one way to do this would be to work with a two dimensional dataset. Firstly there is the remote host; secondly a set of attributes attach to each host such as IP address, files to copy etc. In Python I'd use a nested dictionary but for various reasons I want to use Bash to get this done.

One example is to have an associative array for each remote host like the following:

```
declare -A REMOTE1=([IP]="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" [BACKUPSOURCE]="/homedata")
```

I could then loop through each array so the number of for loops in the script would equal the number of remote hosts:

```
for x in ${REMOTE1[@]}; do
    rsync -a -e 'ssh' ${REMOTE1[IP]}:/${REMOTE1[BACKUPSOURCE]} /localdir
done
```

This seems a bit 'manual' though. It's better than writing out each rsync statement in full but is there a more elegant way of doing this? Perhaps I could have arrays for attributes which I carefully order according to each host and then call a for loop? However that doesn't seem like a sound approach. The real aim would be to automate everything within a single for loop, assuming this didn't get too complicated. I'm guessing that before Python and it's rich data structures, coders using C (and Bash) were able to process multi-dimensional data...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a separate array for each attribute:

```
declare -a hostname ip backupsource

hostname=('remote1' 'remote2' 'remote3')
ip=('111.111.111.111' '222.222.222.222' '333.333.333.333')
backupsource=('bk1' 'bk2' 'bk3')

n=3

for ((i=0;i<n;i++))
do
    echo "####### ${hostname[i]}"
    echo rsync -a -e 'ssh' "${ip[i]}:/${backupsource[i]}" /localdir
done
```

This generates:

```
####### remote1
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 111.111.111.111:/bk1 /localdir
####### remote2
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 222.222.222.222:/bk2 /localdir
####### remote3
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 333.333.333.333:/bk3 /localdir
```

---

---

Using a nameref (`bash 4.3+`) to dynamically reference OP's associative arrays:

```
declare -A remote1 remote2 remote3

remote1=([ip]='111.111.111.111' [backupsource]='bk1')
remote2=([ip]='222.222.222.222' [backupsource]='bk2')
remote3=([ip]='333.333.333.333' [backupsource]='bk3')

n=3

for ((i=1;i<=n;i++))
do
    declare -n _remote="remote$i"       # nameref
    echo "$
    echo rsync -a -e 'ssh' "${_remote[ip]}:/${_remote[backupsource]}" /localdir
done
```

**NOTE:** the name of the nameref (`_remote` in this case) can be any valid identifier (eg, `declare -n x="remote$i"`, `declare -n var="remote$i"`, `declare -n _arr="remote$i"`)

This generates:

```
####### remote1
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 111.111.111.111:/bk1 /localdir
####### remote2
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 222.222.222.222:/bk2 /localdir
####### remote3
rsync -a -e 'ssh' 333.333.333.333:/bk3 /localdir
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. Looking at your first, 'less glamorous' (!) option, it's interesting as you're basically using echo to 'stitch together' the relevant data from the different '1-D' arrays. I was thinking that not having a pre-made data structure like a Python dictionary would make this more complicated in bash but on the contrary, it actually seems simpler.

Comment: I would add, using nameref is obviously more elegant but it's good to have an alternative approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single indexed array formatted like a table:

```
hosts=(
# 1 hostname | 2 ip address  | 3 folder name        | 4 some options
    host1        192.168.0.1     /bkp1                  '*.txt'
    host2        192.168.0.2    '/spaces in name O_o'   '*.py'
    host3        192.168.0.3     /bkp                   '*.sh'
);  C=4            # number of 'columns', set it manually according to 'table'
    N=${#hosts[@]} # number of items in an array
```

Loop over it like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<N; i+=C)); {
    tmp=( "${hosts[@]:$i:$C}" )
    name=${tmp[0]}
    ip=${tmp[1]}
    dir=${tmp[2]}
    opts=${tmp[3]}

    echo "name: $name"
    echo "ip:   $ip"
    echo "dir:  $dir"
    echo "opts: $opts"
    echo "----------"
}
```

The result will be:

```
name: host1
ip:   192.168.0.1
dir:  /bkp1
opts: *.txt
----------
name: host2
ip:   192.168.0.2
dir:  /spaces in name O_o
opts: *.py
----------
name: host3
ip:   192.168.0.3
dir:  /bkp
opts: *.sh
```

---

ps check this project [DDT](https://github.com/vaniacer/DDT)